# Read double values from text file

Tags: c, floating-point

I used following function to read double values from a text file and then convert it into a floating point array, but it ends up with unexpected termination during program running. Can anyone tell me what goes wrong here.

```
float *readFile_double_to_float(char *fileName, int fileSize)
{
    double *array = (double *)malloc(fileSize * sizeof(double *));
    float *array_float = (float *)malloc(fileSize * sizeof(float *));

    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Cannot open file for reading ===> %s\n", fileName);
        exit(1);
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < fileSize; i++)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%lf", array + i);
    };
    fclose(fp);

    for (int i = 0; i < fileSize; i++)
    {
        array_float[i] = (float)array[i];
    };

    printf("CHECK VAL DOUBLE TO FLOAT : float: %.20f | double: %.20f\n", array_float[0], array[0]);

    printf("FILE READ COMPLETED ===> %s\n", fileName);

    free(array);
    return array_float;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(double *)` is the size of a *pointer* to `double`, not a `double` value. On e.g. a 32-bit platform `sizeof(double)` is typically *larger* than `sizeof(double *)`, which means you won't allocate enough memory.

Comment: And why the temporary `double` array? Why not read directly into the `float` array?

Comment: Why all the casting? Don't cast unless you need it.

Comment: regarding: `double *array = (double *)malloc(fileSize * sizeof(double *));` and `float *array_float = (float *)malloc(fileSize * sizeof(float *));`   1) allocate `double` or `float` NOT `double *` or `float *`   2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer, Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "malloc failed" );` so the user is informed of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong size allocated. [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62594837/read-double-values-from-text-file#comment110694834_62594837)

```
//                                          vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv  size of a pointer
double *array = (double *)malloc(fileSize * sizeof(double *));
```

Avoid mistakes, [drop the cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) and allocate to the size of the referenced data.  Easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
double *array = malloc(sizeof *array * fileSize);
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Sizeof referenced data
```

---

Better code would also test allocation success.

```
if (array == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory");
  return NULL;
}
```

---

More informative to use `"%e"`, `"%g"` or  `"%a"`.

```
//printf("CHECK VAL DOUBLE TO FLOAT : float: %.20f | double: %.20f\n", 
printf("CHECK VAL DOUBLE TO FLOAT : float: % .20e | double: % .20e\n", 
    array_float[0], array[0]);
```